# detect change on navigator.online

Tags: javascript, onchange, navigator

How can I detect if the navigator changed your state to online/offline?

something like:

```
var oldState = navigator.onLine; 
window.navigator.onlinechange = function(evnt,newState) { 
         alert('your changed from' + oldState + ' to' + newState + 'state');
}
```

Comment: In fact navigator.onLine does not shows internet availability. It only shows is your computer connected to any network. Use https://github.com/PixelsCommander/OnlineJS instead. It have corresponding callbacks, just include online.js to porject and set window.onLineHandler and window.offLineHandler functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (not every browser supports these events, currently only IE 8,9 and FF > 3 support these events):

```
var el = document.body;
if (el.addEventListener) {
   el.addEventListener("online", function () {
     alert("online");}, true);
   el.addEventListener("offline", function () {
     alert("offline");}, true);
}
else if (el.attachEvent) {
   el.attachEvent("ononline", function () {
     alert("online");});
   el.attachEvent("onoffline", function () {
     alert("offline");});
}
else {
   el.ononline = function () {
     alert("online");};
   el.onoffline = function () {
     alert("offline");};
}
```

The browser support varies, check this out: http://help.dottoro.com/ljnasgpu.php

Answer (score 6):

With the help of classes on body and this code you can find

```
window.ononline = function() {
    alert('You are now online');
}

window.onoffline = function() {
    alert('You are now offline');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it needs to be more cross browser compatible you have to poll the navigator.onLine property.

```
var status = document.getElementById('status')

setInterval(function () {
  status.innerHTML = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';  
}, 250);
```

Demo:
http://html5demos.com/nav-online

Comment: This doesnt work for cross browser ....Only Chrome sets navigator.onLine properly when connectivity is lost. Both Safari and Firefox never set the flag to false if you remove the internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for [online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/online_event) and [offline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/offline_event) event on MDN, They provide examples for the two ways to set an event handler for those events `window.addEventListener("online", eventHandler)` and `window.ononline = eventHandler`. These are the examples they provide:

```
// addEventListener version
window.addEventListener("online", (event) => {
  console.log("You are now connected to the network.");
});

// ononline version
window.ononline = (event) => {
  console.log("You are now connected to the network.");
};

// addEventListener version
window.addEventListener("offline", (event) => {
  console.log("The network connection has been lost.");
});

// onoffline version
window.onoffline = (event) => {
  console.log("The network connection has been lost.");
};
```

For Service Workers you don't have access to `window` so you need to setup the handler in the main JS and forward the changes to the service worker via [`sw.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/postMessage), [Channel Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API) or [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)