# Vue.js - Detect if disconnected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have an Laravel / Vue.js website and i need to detect when we lost the connection to the server and display an warning on the front.

But i can't find a proper way to do that.
I saw that i should use axios like that but i don't know where to put this in my vue...

```
axios.request(options).catch(function(error) {
if (!error.response) {
  // Connect
} 
else {
  // Disconnect
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a property in browsers known as `onLine` which is a boolean that tells the connection status.

Here: `navigator.onLine` returns a boolean according to the connection status.

**UPD:** Also there are some events like `HTMLElement.ononline` and `HTMLElement.onoffline.`

See this SO answer here: [detect change on navigator.online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033193/detect-change-on-navigator-online)

Comment: Nice, and can i use these on an event on each click on the window ? To test continuously if i am online ? ( I speak about performance )

Comment: It will not matter much, since its all based on events, so  you can design a method which on firing an onclick on window,  will return the value of `navigator.onLine`. So you can go with the click approach also.